# State coherency across dependent classes

Tags: c++, state

Suppose there are two classes `Foo` and `Bar`, with `Bar` depending on some state provided by `Foo`. These classes may have a structure as follows:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  // Constructors and destructors

  const State& get_state() const;

  /* Invalidates and recreates the 'State' object passed by 'get_state' */
  void handle_event();

private:
  // private member variables
};

class Bar
{
public:
  Bar(const Foo& foo);

private:
  const State& m_state; //Assigned via foo.get_state()
};
```

Assuming that besides combining both `Foo` and `Bar` into a single class, this the way the `State` must be passed. Furthermore assume that there can be multiple `Bar` classes using the `State` from `Foo`.

When the `handle_event` member function is called what is the pattern or "standard" way of handling the situation such that `Bar` is always in a valid state?

I can imagine that something like `Bar` registering itself with `Foo` during its construction can provide such a mechanism. An example of this is below. The issue with this is I feel it may be too tightly coupled.

```
class Foo
{
public:
  void register_dependency(Bar* bar);
  void deregister_dependency(Bar* bar);

private:
  std::set<Bar *> m_dependencies;
};

class Bar
{
public:
  void invalidate_state(const Foo& foo);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a system like the one you have proposed.  It is a version of the well-established [observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern.

If you think other types besides `Bar` might need state from `Foo`, then you could use an interface to decouple.

```
class Foo;
class IFooStateObserver {
public:
    virtual ~IFooStateObserver() {}
    virtual void invalidate_state(const Foo& foo) = 0;
};

class Foo {
public:
    void register_dependency(IFooStateObserver* observer);
    void deregister_dependency(IFooStateObserver* observer);

private:
    std::set<IFooStateObserver*> m_dependencies;
};

class Bar : public IFooStateObserver {
public:
    void invalidate_state(const Foo& foo) override;
};
```

A similar system could isolate `Foo` from `Bar` if necessary.